# drawTextOnPath does not render the text properly

Tags: android, ondraw, circular-slider

I want to draw a circle and a pointer which moves along the path. I am able to write text properly on the path. But on the pointer the text gets truncated/overlapped. Tried increasing the textSize and the spanSize with no gain. Below is the code.

```
        canvas.drawPath(mCirclePonterPath, mPointerPaint);

        numberPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        numberPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        numberPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        numberPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
        numberPaint.setTextSize(65f);

        canvas.drawTextOnPath("10",mCirclePonterPath,0,0,numberPaint);
```

Attached is the image for reference.

[image: The pointer is the black circle where I want to display the number 10]

Comment: Are you using any jQuery plugin or your own code ? Have you tried http://roundsliderui.com/, which is a jQuery plugin with lot of customization options. It maybe suitable for your requirement...

Comment: I need to do an android native app. How do I use the plugin?

Comment: For native app we can't use this.. For hybrid app only we can use this..